# 3 events A, B and C such that A⊂B⊂C. P(A)=1/6, P(B)=1/4. P(C)=1/2. What is P(~A∩C) and P(BU(~A∩C)?

Tags: probability

3 events A, B and C such that A⊂B⊂C. P(A)=1/6, P(B)=1/4. P(C)=1/2. What is P(~A∩C) and P(BU(~A∩C)?

So far I have: P(~A∩C) <= P(~A) = 5/6. 
P(~A∩C)=P(~A) or P(C)-P(A∩C)=1-P(A)=1-1/6=5/6

Idk if that's correct?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(\sim A\cap C)$ is the event of being in $C$ and not being in $A$. Since $A$ is in $C$, 
$$P(\sim A\cap C) = P(C) - P(A)=\frac12-\frac16=\frac13$$

For $P(B\cup(\sim A\cap C))$. Since every element of $A$ are in $B$, then
$$B\cup(\sim A\cap C) = C$$
and
$$P(B\cup(\sim A\cap C))=P(C)=\frac12$$